# Unique parameterization of size MxN matrices of rank k

Tags: linear-regression

Any rank k matrix $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ can be written as:
$$ Y = UV'$$
Where $U\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times k}, V\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$. This factorization is not unique since for any invertible matrix $R\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ the factorization 
$$Y = (UR)(VR^{-1})'=UV'$$
This means there is a $k^2$-dimensional manifold of solutions (the amount of parameters needed to describe the matrix $R$). The factorization itself has $km +kn$ parameters and $k^2$ are redundant so the total number of parameters is: $$km+kn-k^2$$
If I could find a unique parameterization, I could let $\beta$ be the column vector with these parameters and then find a matrix $X$ such that:
$$\text{vec} (Y)_i = \sum_j \beta_j X_{i,j}$$ I'm attempting to find a unique parameterization so that I can treat low rank approximations as a multilinear regression (technically weighted low rank approximations).

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more unique parametrization is the Singular Value Decomposition
$Y = U D V^T$ where $D$ is $k \times k$ diagonal with positive diagonal elements
(which we may choose to be in sorted order) and $U$ and $V$ are $m \times k$ and $n \times k$ with orthonormal columns.  This is unique up to multiplication of the columns of both $U$ and $V$ corresponding to each distinct singular value by an orthogonal matrix on the right.  In particular, if the singular values are all distinct the only freedom is to multiply the same set of columns of both $U$ and $V$ by $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to make the decomposition unique. $U$ can be any matrix with the same column-space as $Y$ and $V'$ any matrix with the same row-space. Given either, the other is uniquely determined. Here is one way:

Let $U$ be the leftmost set of $k$ independent columns of $Y.$ Then $V'$ will be the unique reduced row echelon matrix equivalent to $Y$ with the bottom $m-k$ all zero rows deleted.

This has the property that row operations on $Y$ leave $V$ unchanged but act in the same way on $U$ while row operations leave $U$ unchanged but act in the same way on $V'.$

Some properties like this would narrow things down. You might want that the representation of $Y'$ is $V,U'.$

What would you want to happen in the case $m=n=k?$ Then the simple scheme I define has $U=Y$ and $V=I.$ Or what about the case that $Y$ is a $k \times k$ diagonal matrix padded with $0$'s to make it the right shape?

An answer to either or both of those would narrow things down.